# GPG keys issue while installing mysql-community-server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, package

While Installing **mysql-community-server** getting bellow error:

**Command:**

```
 sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

**Error:**

```
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/2/mysql57-community/packages/mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.37-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3a79bd29: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql


The GPG keys listed for the "MySQL 5.7 Community Server" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.


 Failing package is: mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.37-1.el7.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Can anyone help on this...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 126):

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checking-rpm-signature.html

There is no separate signature. RPM packages have a built-in GPG signature and MD5 checksum.

rpm also supports loading the key directly from a URL:

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023
```

Comment: This worked for me on Amazon linux 2

Comment: Worked for me on centos 7.9 / aws ec2 - using the "rpm import..." - THANKS!

Comment: Worked for me for Oracle Linux 7

Comment: Worked on Centos 7

Comment: Worked on Fedora 35

Comment: Add sudo at the beginning is necessary for my case

Comment: Worked for amazon-linux 2 machine thanks

Comment: It worked for my on aws linux 2. Thanks

Comment: Tested and worked on Rocky Linux 9.

Comment: This key is now expired since 2023-12-14, you should update your answer to use https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2023 instead.

Comment: worked for me on registry.redhat.io/ubi9:9.3-1610

Answer (score 8):

The GPG keys for the new release has been changed. See this for further info:
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4419382481815?input_string=gpg+keys+problem+with+mysql+5.7

Steps to resovled this error the updated MySQL GPG will need to be installed.

1. For existing systems, the MySQL repository file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ will need to have its 'gpgkey' line adjusted to:

   gpgkey=https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022

Once adjusted, run the update once more:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/upcp
```

2. For new installations you can import the key before running the installer:

   rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022

Ubuntu:

```
wget -q -O https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 | apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with two DNS-ONLY servers.

I edited the /etd/yum.repos.d/Mysql57.repo file and changed all the "gpgcheck=1" lines to "gpgcheck=0"

Then I executed yum update

Then I edited the /etd/yum.repos.d/Mysql57.repo file and changed all the "gpgcheck=0" lines back to "gpgcheck=1"

Finally, I updated the cPanel software.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but i resolve it by running 
````
sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
````
before the 
````
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
````

and its just works fine!!!

Comment: It's a workaround when you are in a DMZ server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the following.

With rpm based installations:

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

Apt based:

```
wget -q -O - https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 | apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me on Debian 11:

```
wget --quiet --output-document - https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql2022.gpg --import
chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql2022.gpg
```

Before that `apt-get update` reported the key error, after that all good.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions dont work for you, disabling GPG check worked for me immediately, since I could not make other suggestions work in the moment.

I edited the
`sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d//etc/mysql-community.repo`

Then scroll to where you will find mysql version causing issues for me was 5.7

```
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Change `gpgcheck=1` to `gpgcheck=0` and try again the installation.

This will cause the system to ignore gpgcheck for mysql. Please note, security wise its not advisable, but its a quick work around if you are not concerned about packages security