# Problem installing MySQL 5.6 on Rocky Linux 9

Tags: mysql

I´m triying to install MySQL 5.6 Database Server on Rocky Linux, I already configure the repository but en some part of the installation throws an error:

> Cannot download file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql: All mirrors were tried
> The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Thanks!

I run:

> yum clean packages

but it not helps

Comment: is there a good reason, not to use 5.7 or 8.0?

Comment: Yes, where I work we use an application that only uses 5.6 :(

Comment: see: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/?version=5.6.42&os=2  (P.S. I do not have experience with if that version works on "Rocky Linux 9"  !)

Comment: take alook at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239450/gpg-keys-issue-while-installing-mysql-community-server all packages shuld have built in gpg keys